# Accordion with a link to external resource

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I am trying to have an accordion with whole header DIV clickable which also includes a link which does not influence accordion status but instead open an external link in new a tab/windows.

but if I do this, header is capturing click event on my link and it toggles accordion status only.

Example code:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
      <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a><br />
      whole heder is<br />
      clickable<br />
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LUzwP/6/

is it at all possible to implement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Forked to http://jsfiddle.net/ZPLff/

changes :

```js
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" id="google">

$("#google").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});​
```

reason : `data-toggle="collapse"` (in collapsible data-api) calls `e.preventDefault()` in its `.on.click()`-handler, so you have to prevent this

Comment: Really good. IMHO needs to be added to JQuery UI Accordion documentation.