# JQuery UI makes my link non-clickable

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I just imported the JQuery UI "[accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)" control into my project. I then tried to modify the header of the accordion by adding a link around an image:

[image]

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3><img src="icon.ico" class="favIcn" />
  <span class="hdrPageTitle" title="Some user prompt">Section 2</span>
  <a class="hdrLink" href="http://example.com/" target="_blank"></a></h3>
```

where the CSS for it is:

```
.hdrLink{
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-image:url(link_icn.png);
    width: 14px;
    height: 7px;
}
```

But the problem I'm experiencing is that my link doesn't work. When I click it, it simply closes or opens the accordion tab.

How do I make it clickable?

PS. Here's [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35eut890/) to show the issue. I guess there's no CSS needed. Just a simple `<a>` link doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: @Kiran: I haven't done it before. Does it support JQuery UI inclusion?

Comment: @c00000fd you can load external ressources

Comment: did u try `$('#accordion').find('a[href*='+ url + ']').trigger('click');`

Comment: @Khaleel: Can you explain what does it do?

Comment: @Kiran: Added a fiddle link in the description. Thanks.

Comment: did you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681265/accordion-with-a-link-to-external-resource

Comment: @Kiran: Thanks. All I need to add is this script: `$(".hdrLink").click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});` Do you want to post it separately and I'll mark it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

**JS:**

```
$(".hdrLink").click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems click is prevented by your J-Query because when you click on `<a>` same time you click on `accordion` div so I suppose it `return false` or `prevent default` so you need to modify you existing script or handle your `<a>` Element click event to make it work.

Here is fiddle help you out  http://jsbin.com/pecatahaseho/1/

**EDIT**

you also can use

```
$("#accordion a").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use z-index property and set is to higher value with  !important in your css class.
Like z-index:9999  !important;
(If it is due to overlapping ,then problem will be solved by this only)

If it not works then try to remove the "return" statement from your jQuery ..If you are using the return statement then it will cancel the effect of click event.

Comment: I did try `z-index` before and it didn't help. As for using `return`, I don't do much JavaScript with the JQuery besides just instantiating the control.